# Using a reference from one XML file in a different java file in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making an android studio project and I have two different XML files I want to use in one java file.
So in my java file I want the equivalent of

```
setContentView(xml1)
.....
setContentView(xml2)
.....
```

I'm only using a single image in one file which I want to reference (There are other things in the xml but for simplicity I want to only reference the image). 
Is there any way I can do this?
Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in the scene transition APIs: https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/scenes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can include other layouts in your main layout.  For example, you could have layout.xml that contains:

```
<include layout="@layout/layout1" />
<include layout="@layout/layout2" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to include the whole xml file, just one specific element of that xml file

Comment: can't these sub layout files just include the elements you want?

Comment: No I'm doing stuff to the xml in different java files.
I need to only get the specific element through my java class, but I don't want to "set content view x"